# Using javascript, how do I copy svg tspan elements inside an svg text element into a different text element?

Tags: javascript, svg, tspan

I have an svg text element with two tspan elements.  It looks like this.

```
<text id="majNote5" x="25" y="70">
    <tspan>D</tspan>
    <tspan font-family="'Opus Text'" font-size="25">b</tspan>
</text>
```

I have a 2nd empty text element which looks like this.

```
<text id="majChord1" x="425" y="70" ></text>
```

I want to copy both tspan elements and their respective texts in the first text element into the 2nd text element.

I tried the following:

```
var majNote5 = document.getElementById('majNote5');
var majChord1 = document.getElementById('majChord1');

majChord1.textContent = majNote5.textContent;
```

This does copy the text contents of the tspan elements and places it in the other container, but without any of the tspan elements.  So afterward it looks like this:

```
<text id="majChord1" x="25" y="70">Db</text>
```

How do I get the second text container to look exactly like the first container?

Thanks,
--christopher

Comment: you would have to loop through each children, and copy each of those. Or, you could just do `var clone = document.getElementById('majNote5').cloneNode(true);
var majChord1 = document.getElementById('majChord1');  clone.id=majChord1.id; majChord1.parentNode.replaceChild(clone, majChord1);`

Comment: That worked very well.  You may want to submit that as an answer.  One thing to note, each time the node was replaced, the variable pointing to  `document.getElementById('majChord1')` no longer had a reference and had to be declared again with the new node.